# Android: getting info on the calling app from activity

Tags: android, validation, android-intent, android-activity

I want to implement a fine-granularity protection mechanism in an exported activity. The permissions framework does not seem to work for my requirements.

There are two options I am considering:

- using Activity.getCallingPackage - only works if the activity is started with startActivityForResult - this is a limitation I would like to avoid if possible.
- using Binder.getCallingUid - when called in an Activity, it returns the local UID, and not the calling UID.

Is there any way to allow activities started with startActivity to retrieve any information about the calling app?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra information in your intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextClass.class);
i.putExtra("extra", "This is some extra information";
startActivity(i);
```

You retrieve the data from NextClass by:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String extraStuff = i.getStringExtra("extra");
```

Comment: I want to allow access to certain features in my activity only to trusted clients. Intents cannot be trusted, any app could add the extra info. The protection scheme I am thinking about has all trusted apps include some signed metadata in the app manifest. To read it, I have to get access to the PackageInfo for the calling app.

Comment: Ah sorry, I do not have any suggestions for that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to allow activities started with startActivity to retrieve any information about the calling app?

No, sorry, beyond your `startActivityForResult()` hack. Android's support for "a fine-granularity protection mechanism" is designed around services, not activities or other components.

Comment: Thanks. This is unfortunate. I am surprised few other seem to have this issue, seems like a pretty basic security enabler.

Comment: @user2577593: IMHO, this has nothing really to do with security. What you are trying to implement is a licensing system, whereby only licensed apps ("trusted parties") can do things. Android does not have an inter-app licensing framework as part of its IPC model. If the "trusted parties" are all your own apps, you can use signature-level permissions, which does not require any knowledge of who the requester is, other than that it is signed with the same signing key as yours.

Comment: I am providing an SDK (as activities), and do not own the calling apps. I have considered the signature protection level, however a) the calling apps will likely have to be signed multiple times (once with the company key, and a second time with the SDK key), and b) the keys used to signed the apps cannot be changed for app updates. This is big limitation if these client apps have already been released and integrate the SDK at a later time. Since it would allow me to create the custom licensing mechanism, I consider the ability to retrieve the caller's identity as a security enabler.

Comment: @user2577593: "the calling apps will likely have to be signed multiple times (once with the company key, and a second time with the SDK key)" -- AFAIK, that's not supported. "I consider the ability to retrieve the caller's identity as a security enabler" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion.